# Why does the 404 view fail to display for routes with params in this Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have been working on an SPA with Vue 3, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB) API.

I am currently working on a 404 page.

In `src\router\index.ts` I have:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue';
import TopRatedMoviesView from '../views/TopRatedMoviesView.vue';
import MovieDetailsView from '../views/MovieDetailsView.vue';
import ActorDetailsView from '../views/ActorDetailsView.vue';
import NotFoundView from '../views/NotFoundView.vue';

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/top-rated',
    name: 'top_rated',
    component: TopRatedMoviesView
  },
  {
    path: '/movie/:id',
    name: 'movie_details',
    component: MovieDetailsView
  },
  {
    path: '/actor/:id',
    name: 'actor_details',
    component: ActorDetailsView
  },
  {
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    name: "404",
    component: NotFoundView
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

In `src\views\NotFoundView.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="container d-flex">
   <div class="text-center">
      <h1 class="mb-3">404 | page not found</h1>
      <router-link class="btn btn-sm btn-success" to="/">
        <strong>Go to the Homepege</strong>
      </router-link>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'NotFoundView',

  });
</script>
```

The 404 view is displayed (as expected) when a random string is right after the root URL: `http://localhost:8080/someNonExistingPath`.

But the same does *not* happen when a "bad" parameter is provided to a dynamic route: `http://localhost:8080/movie/a615656`.

What am I doing wrong? What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: What is responsible for determining that "a615656" is a bad value? From the router's perspective _any_ value matches the route.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console or something relevant in your Vue devtools? Like the path you are currently on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible cause for this when you access `/movie/a615656` URL, it still satisfies the route parameter `/movie/:id`. Because sometimes, `id` can also contain non-numeric characters.

To fix this, you can either use route REGEX to filter out non-numeric values, OR manually throw the 404 view.

For example, in your `getMovieDetails` method, you can look for non-alphanumeric character and throw an the `404` view. But this causes inconsistency because even when the `id` satisfies, the item with the `id` may not be available on the server side, so your best bet is to throw `404` in `catch` method, for example:

```
.catch((err) => {
    //log error
    console.log(err);
    //if the error status is 404
    if (err.response.status == 404) {
        router.push({ name: '404' })
    }
});
```

This may result in a small delay because you have to wait for the response from the server, but this is how you are supposed to do it. Even in Nuxt [guide](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#example-1), they provided the following sample code:

```
const route = useRoute()
const { data } = await useFetch(`/api/movies/${route.params.slug}`)
if (!data.value) {
  throw createError({ statusCode: 404, statusMessage: 'Page Not Found' })
}
```

That was just an example, no need to worry if you are not familiar with NuxtJS